# include front matter from another MD file

Tags: jekyll

I use Jekyll to maintain a bilingual website. Most pages are generated from a corresponding markdown file, but several English/Japanese pairs are generated from a single markdown because its contents are duplicated.

For example, these pages

- http://www.isee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/CR/en/members/
- http://www.isee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/CR/members/

are generated from the following files.

- _includes/cr_pages/members.md
- members_en.md
- members.md

But members_en.md and members.md include the first file, which switches the content language with many if statements.

**Question**

I would like to know how to include a front matter from the first file. I do not want to repeat putting duplicated front matter lines in the second and third files.

**Update**

`_includes/cr_pages/members.md`

```
{% assign lang = page.lang %}
{% if lang == 'ja' %}
Japanese text
{% else %}
English text
{% endif %}
```

`members.md`

```
---
layout: page
title: CR 研の構成員
permalink: /members/
ref: members
lang: ja
---
{% include cr_pages/members.md %}
```

`members_en.md`

```
---
layout: page
title: Members
permalink: /en/members/
ref: members
lang: en
---
{% include cr_pages/members.md %}
```

My website is based on the method written on this page.

https://www.sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/

What I want to do is to put a front matter variable "lastmod" in the first file, which is automatically added by git pre-commit hook.

I use this variable to show the last modification date on posts and pages. You can see an example here.

http://www.isee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/CR/en/research/interactions/

Comment: Am I correct, you want to access the frontmatter of `_includes/cr_pages/members.md` in `members*.md` or vice versa? Although i think that this is not possible, can you provide more information on these files? However, you can build a mulitlanguage-site without plugins and too much code by using [data](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/), [defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) and some liquid. I've done this for my page and did not have to repeat anything. Localization of date and hreflang-tags included...

Comment: > access the frontmatter of _includes/cr_pages/members.md in members*.md or vice versa

Yes, exactly. I will update my question.

Comment: Ok... i think, i understood your problem. Would it be an option to store the `lastmod` in the `members*.md` files and pass this value as a parameter in the include like: `{% include cr_pages/members.md lastmod=page.lastmod %}`. The parameter is available in the variable `{{ include.lastmod }}` inside the include.

Comment: Thank you again. 'lastmod' is automatically updated by git pre-commit hook and I want to show it in generated HTML files. `members.md` and `members_end.md` are not updated in future as their content is almost empty. So passing `lastmod` from `members.md` to `_includes/cr_pages/members.md` is meaningless.